# Calculating maximum induced current problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-current, angular-velocity, electromagnetic-induction

I have this problem about magnetic fields and induction.

The figure shows a wire that has been bent into a circular arc of radius $r = 27.0 cm$, centered at $O$. A straight wire $OP$ can be rotated about $O$ and makes sliding contact with the arc at $P$. Another straight wire $OQ$ completes the conducting loop. The three wires have cross‐sectional area $А = 1.32 {mm}^2$ and resistivity $ρ = 4.05 × 10^{-8}$ Ω·m, and the apparatus lies in a uniform magnetic field of magnitude $B = 0.190 T$ directed out of the figure. Wire $OP$ begins from rest at angle $θ = 0$ and has constant angular acceleration of $12.0 rad/s^2$. As functions of $θ$ (in rad), find (a) the loop's resistance and (b) the magnetic flux through the loop. (c) For what $θ$ is the induced current maximum and (d) what is that maximum?

[image: Figure]

This is what I have been trying:

[image: Solution]

The thing is, I am able to take the derivative and find out the $\theta$ is $2$ radians. But when I use that fact and use the equation $\displaystyle i_{max} = \frac{|\epsilon|}{R} = \frac{Br^2\omega}{2R}$, I end up with the number at part d. Unfortunately, it says  it is not correct. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas to solve in another way maybe?

Comment: It looks like you're showing work and trying to understand where you're going wrong. Great! Unfortunately, I don't understand the work you've shown. For example, I don't know what the images showing $\rho r (2+\theta)/A$ and $Br^2 \theta/2$ are supposed to be telling us. Could you maybe show what you tried more explicitly, perhaps with math instead of images of equations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got your equation for $i_{max}$, but did you do it this way?

The equation for $\phi_B$ through the loop as a function of $\theta$ as you found in b) is:

$\phi_B=\frac{Br^2\theta}{2}$

$emf=\frac{d\phi_B}{dt}=\frac{d\phi_B}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{Br^2}{2}*\omega$

$i=\frac{emf}{R}=\frac{emf}{\frac{\rho r(2+\theta)}{A}}=\frac{ABr\omega}{2\rho(2+\theta)}=\frac{ABr\sqrt{2\alpha\theta}}{2\rho(2+\theta)}$

To find the angle at which $i_{maximum}$ occurs, differentiate in $\theta$ and equate to $0$

You will find $i_{max}$ occurs at $\theta=2 $

Put that in the equation for i and you should get the right answer.